# Cannnot build java project in Eclipse: Parent of resource is marked 'read-only'

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run a java project in Eclipse Kepler. The product runs fine on another machine, and I used `git clone` and `Import` to load the project on my current machine.

However, upon loading the project, I received the error:
The project was not built due to "Parent of resource: /Users/adam/.../mockup/bin is marked as read-only.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent   mockup      Unknown Java Problem

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Mark the indicated folder as read-write.  This is a file system issue, has nothing to do with java or eclipse.

Comment: The problem is there is no `mockup/bin` folder, I assume since the project hasn't been built.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by granting write access to my workspace folder.

Some hints of how doing that in Linux can be found at: [Change read/write access of a folder in Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917786/change-read-write-access-of-a-folder-in-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 1):

if changing existing file permissions is not possible, you can also specify the build folder separately (assuming you are able to write your changes into the .project file).

Right-click the project and click properties -> Build path

In there, change the default output folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I resolved by changing the permissions of the project folders I was importing, not the workspace folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was showing inside target folder.

I deleted all content inside target folder and rebuild the project !

:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same proplem. To solve it you have to open ou create a new project on eclipse as **super user**.

Linux:
execute the command `sudo su`

Windows: Open as Admin